# SQL Server value update from another table only if not null

Tags: sql-server, null, sql-update

I am trying to update a column of a table A with the values in table B column based on if `Table A.col1 = TableB.Col1`.

Problem: I overwrite TableA column value with `Null` if `Col1` is not found in `TableB.Col1`.

My current query is

```
UPDATE [tableA]
SET col2 = (SELECT col2 FROM [tableB] WHERE [TableB].col1 = [TableA].col1)
```

How can I avoid this?

Ex: TableA

```
Col1 Col2
1    100
2    200
3    300
```

TableB

```
Col1 Col2
1    1000
3    3000
```

Resulting table should be:

Table A

```
Col1 Col2
1    1000
2    200
3    3000
```

But I get:

```
Col1 Col 2
1    1000
2    null
3    3000
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
UPDATE [tableA]
SET col2 = COALESCE(
             (SELECT col2 FROM [tableB] WHERE [TableB].col1 = [TableA].col1),
             col2)
```

[`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) returns the first non-NULL expression among its arguments.

Or, you could do:

```
UPDATE a
SET col2 = b.col2
FROM TableA a
    INNER JOIN
     TableB b
        ON
            a.col1 = b.col1
```

but you should be aware that this second form is SQL Server dialect, not standard SQL.

Comment: fantastic, thanks for the answer, used the 1st one, it worked a treat.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to update the whole table so your query needs a `where` clause. In this case :

```
WHERE exists (select 1 
                from [tableB] 
                where [TableB].col1=[TableA].col1 
                  and [TableB].col2 is not NULL -- that condition may or may not be needed 
             )
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, no?

```
UPDATE [tableA]
SET col2= (select col2 from [tableB] where [TableB].col1=[TableA].col1 and [TableB].col1 IS NOT NULL )
```

Comment: No that doesnt seem to work. All values not in table B are now null in table A. Did you test it your side?